# Django - preset foreign key value in form field

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm struggling to figure this out and hoping someone here can help me. I have a model, called "Team", which has a ForeignKey field that corresponds to the page I'm showing the ModelForm on ("Department").  Since it's on the page I want to set the ForeignKey in the backend (View or Form) rather than have the user select it.

Following others examples I set it up so the value would be added in the form portion, but when I submit the form I get the following error (followed by the request.POST print out) in the terminal:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>Department<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['KeEJF7KFr6l9dbkmZWA7u4Qg3eKqqFGcB2qq2AIEmilLP87AySi60ig3hJl6TBS0'], 'title': ['test'], 'description': [''], 'events': [''], 'current_status': [''], 'notes': [''], 'impact': [''], 'timeliness': [''], 'likelihood': [''], 'risk': [''], 'summary': [''], 'documents': ['']}>
```

**FORM:**

```
class TeamFormCreate(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('department', 'title', 'description', 'events', 'current_status', 'notes', 'impact',
                  'timeliness', 'likelihood', 'risk', 'summary', 'documents')
```

**VIEW:**

```
@login_required
def new_team(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TeamFormCreate(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            team = form.save(commit=False)
            team.author = request.user
            team.modified_date = timezone.now()
            team.save()
            return redirect('/dashboard/1')
        else:
            return redirect('/dashboard/1')

    else:
        cd_id = request.GET.get('id', None)
        form = TeamFormCreate(cd_id)
        return render(request, 'app/sidebar_team.html', {'form': form})
```

**MODEL:**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey('MyApp.Department', related_name='teams')
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    events = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    current_status = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # icon = models.ImageField()

    # Document files
    summary = models.FileField(upload_to='team', blank=True, null=True)
    documents = models.FileField(upload_to='team', blank=True, null=True)

    # Ratings
    RATING_CHOICES = [(x, x) for x in range(1, 6)]
    impact = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    timeliness = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    likelihood = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    risk = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: I don't know if its just a typo, but in your models you have `DepartMent` (with uppercase M) and in your form `Department` (just capitalized).

Comment: That's a typo from when I was masking the model names.

Comment: maybe you can see this question with similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/49463287/924300

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis thanks for the suggestion, it got me to the correct answer.  Rather than passing in the title from the model, I passed in the pk of the model and that did it.

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis, maybe I spoke too soon.  This works for creating the form and setting the value, but when I try to submit the form it rejects it citing that it can't find the Department value.

Comment: in your class Team change the foreign key Department to lowercase department

Comment: In your code in view you have a teamUpdateForm and your question you have a GroupFormCreate ?  and please post your urlpattern

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis I was able to fix the issue by creating a new View Class (per your link above) and then adding a post function inside of it.  This wasn't my finest post by a long shot, so thanks for hanging in and helping!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this working by changing my View from a function based view to the following class based view.

```
# Required Imports
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class TeamCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = TeamFormCreate
    template_name = 'app/sidebar_team.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        pk = self.request.GET.get('id')
        return {
            'department': pk,
        }

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = TeamFormUpdate(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            team = form.save(commit=False)
            team.author = request.user
            team.modified_date = timezone.now()
            team.save()
            return redirect('/dashboard/' + str(team.department.id))
        else:
            return redirect('/dashboard/' + str(form.department.id))
```